# What is the best way to relate rows in the same table

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to design a table of rows, each row can relate in some manner to another row.

On the practical level we are talking about layers of soil (archaeology).

One row - one layer - is above another layer, essentially A is above B is above C, equally C is below B is below A. In a graph database this would be very trivial, unfortunately we are using a relational database. Each relation ship has a direction, A is above B, but B is not above A. The data will be added as A is above B although we may want to search and find what is above B, with or without being explicit about this relationship, if A is above B then B must be below A. A further complication is that D could equal E, as in it is the same as, so D=E and E=D, however this is not directional because the relationship is true both ways.

So that's the logic.

But, what is the best way to design some tables to allow this? I should note we use PostgreSQL and Django.

A basic example follows.

```
Table name: Layer
id
Layer_name
```

I assume we need a second table like the following:

```
Table name: Relationship
id
layer_id1
relationship
layer_id2
```

I have also seen the use of the REFERENCES for non-directional relationships, as stated [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48568/how-to-relate-two-rows-in-the-same-table).

I mention we are using Django, can/should the frontend do any sanitisation or tricks like if statements, if A is above B then also enter B is below A, if A=B or B=A only enter A equals B.

Any constructive advice is welcome.

Comment: How are you looking to enter the data? A single column in the table with the "level" would suffice even if it was not unique?

Comment: While directionality is not required in your relational data model definition, it can be enforced both in the data entity and relation definitions, or in addition, or instead, as well as in the queries used to retrieve it.  Are you familiar with OUTER JOINS?  See [Postgres Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html)

Comment: First both layers have to be in the layers table (hence thinking about REFERENCES syntax) only then can it be related to another pre-existing layer. 

I've used outer joins before.

Comment: A non-symetrical self referencing ManyToManyField would work if you are using Django models

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to represent the layers as a graph (or a many-to-many relationship using a junction table) in PostgreSQL, doing so would make it costly to run queries that compare nonadjacent layers, because you would need to make many joins to traverse the sequence of relationships.

It may be simpler to add a column for the layers of soil that allows you to order them and make comparisons.

The easiest way to model that is to introduce a numeric column. You can think of this column ad a number that allows you to order the layers vertically.

The column would look like

```
level double precision NOT NULL
```

The first layer can be set to an arbitrary starting value, such as `level = 0.0`.

If you add a layer above or below all others, its `level` will be 1 more than the maximum or 1 less than the minimum.

To add a layer between two existing ones, set its `level` to the arithmetic mean of the adjacent layers. For example, to add a layer between a layer at level 2.0 and a layer at 3.0, set the new layer level to 2.5.

To query for adjacent layers, you can sort by the difference in level values, with negative differences below and positive differences above.

Comment: The problem with the level value is it doesn't maintain the relationship between level within structures. Lets say A (level 1) is above B (level 2) and A' (A prime) (level 1) is above B' (level 2) says nothing about A to B' .  Perhaps A-B is in U.S Pacific NW and A'-B' is South Africa. You need a graph (M:M) or a hierarchy (1:M) to keep that straight. That then depends upon the answer can A and C both above B? And can B be above D and E?

Comment: Valid criticism. But OP didn't describe such constraints. I'll wait for the verdict, perhaps this simple model that would work for a smaller area is good enough.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted OP to be aware of the limitation. And description is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 2):

As Iain Shelvington mentioned, it seems like the best approach for your case is Django's self-referencing, non-symmetrical [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
class SoilLayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lower_layers = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",                     #each layer can point to other layers
        symmetrical=False,          #relationships are directional (i.e. upper/lower)
        related_name="upper_layers" #look up reverse relationships easily
        )
```

Then you can create your layers and order them:

```
D = SoilLayer.objects.create(name="D")
C = SoilLayer.objects.create(name="C")
B = SoilLayer.objects.create(name="B")
B.lower_layers.add(C, D)
A = SoilLayer.objects.create(name="A")
A.lower_layers.add(B)
```

Finally, you can search for them:

```
A.lower_layers.all();    #returns B
B.lower_layers.all();    #returns C and D
C.upper_layers.all();    #returns B
D.upper_layers.all();    #returns B
```